# Replacing integers in a mathematical expression

Tags: python, string, replace, floating-point, integer

I have a large mathematical expression in a txt file that looks something like this,

```
Z3N = -24*y[1]*r*pow(EXP,-2.0*phi)*y[5]*y[5]+(32*r-44*y[1]*r+32*r*y[4])
```

only much longer. What I'd like to do is write a python code that will change all the integers appearing above into floats. So 24 becomes 24.0, 32 becomes 32.0. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: There is no divison involved. What difference will it make?

Comment: I'm assuming that you want to exclude the integers `1`,`5`, and `4` as well, because list indices need to be integers, not floats?

Comment: Yes, I need to leave the numbers in the square brackets untouched. The expression will be divided later, by another very long expression. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I have no idea why you'd want to do this, you can use RegExes to accomplish this easily. Do:

```
import re
Z3N = re.sub(r"\b(?<!\.)(\d+)(?!\.)\b", r"\1.0", Z3N)
```

If you do not want to match the list indices use this RegEX:

```
\b(?<!\.|\[)(\d+)(?!\.|\])\b
```

**EDIT:** Added explanation.
The `(\d+)` matches any number of digits, i.e. any integer, and captures it for later use.

The `(?<!\.|\[)` is called a negative lookbehind, that means the integer must not be preceded by either a dot or a opening square bracket, thereby excluding any indices and the numbers that are already part of a float, i.e. the `.0`. The `\b`is called a word boundary and mathches where where word and non-word characters 'switch', as digits are considered word characters this excludes numbers that are part of an identifier.
The `(?!\.|\[)` is a negative lookahead and does basically the same thing an the look behind, it does not match the digits that are proceeded by a dot or closing sqaure brachets, thereby excluding indices and floats again.
The last `\b`ensures that a number that is the first character of an identifier is not replaced, for the reason explained above.

**EDIT:** Further explanations.
The `\1.0` is the replacement string, that means every match is replaced with this string. The `\1` is replaced by the content of the first capture group, which happens to be the integer matched. That means that as a replacement you get the original integer with `.0` appended, making a float out of the integer.
And yes, `r` treats every character literally. The `\` inside the RegEx are not replaced with other characters, but are literal. The RegEx engine gives a special meaning to them, however.

Comment: That will also act on digit groups in words, like `Z3N` and `alpha2`, which probably isn't intended.

Comment: True, I didn't think of that as it didn't occur in the given example, edited my answer!

Comment: Yes, I'd like to only change the bare integers, and leave alone the list indices in square brackets untouched, as well as the numbers in the parameter names like Z3N.

Comment: Could you explain what each of the parts in that RegEX means and how it works. This is great, I think I have it working!

Comment: Thanks that's really clear. And the final "\1.0"? Does this divide the selected numbers by 1.0 and turn them into floats?

Also, I thought that using r in front of a string "..." will treat the characters in the string literally. So why aren't the regEx expressions taken literally?